# How do I get a refresh token in microsoft OAuth for my app in Microsoft Teams when the user needs to consent?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, refresh-token

I have an app for Microsoft teams that uses Azure SSO login.

The authentication flow is as follows:

1. When a user opens the app in a channel in Teams, the front-end fetches the `sso-token` from Microsoft graph API and sends it to back-end.
2. On receiving the soo-token, the back-end makes a call to `/token` route of Microsoft graph API with the `sso-token` and `scopes` (including `offline_access`) to fetch the `access_token` and `refresh_token`.
3. If the user has already consented or the admin has consented on the user's behalf, then there is no issue and the back-end is getting both `refresh_token` as well as `access_token` and the back-end returns `200` status.
   But if consent is required, then the back-end sends a `403` status back to the front-end.
4. Upon receiving `403` status, the front-end now starts the consent flow and makes a call to `/authorize` route with `client-id` and `scopes` (including `offline_access`). In this case, after the user has consented, I am not getting the `refresh_token` from Microsoft, instead only `access_token` is returned.

Now, I have a feature to send Microsoft teams activity notifications to users from the app and for that, I need to refresh the access token from time to time without user interaction as the process of sending activity notifications is happening from the back-end. And since the back-end is not getting the `refresh_token` in the scenario where user consent was required, after some time the `access_token` saved in the back-end is expiring and all the API calls for sending activity notifications result in an error.

## The Back-end code for the step 2

1. Utility function for fetching the `access_token` and `refresh_token` using `sso-token` in the back-end.

```js
// other import statements
//...
const {
  MS_CLIENT_ID,
  MS_CLIENT_SECRET,
  MS_GRAPH_SCOPES,
} = require('../config/env');

const graphScopes = `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/${MS_GRAPH_SCOPES} offline_access`;

// receives the sso-token as parameter from front-end
const getAccessToken = async (ssoToken) => {
  try {
    const { tid } = jwt_decode(ssoToken);
    if (!tid) throw new Error('sso token is malformed');

    const accessTokenQueryParams = new URLSearchParams({
      grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
      client_id: MS_CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: MS_CLIENT_SECRET,
      assertion: ssoToken,
      scope: graphScopes,
      requested_token_use: 'on_behalf_of',
    }).toString();

    const { data, status } = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tid}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: accessTokenQueryParams,
    });
    if (status != 200) throw new Error('could not exchange access token');

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error({
      function: 'getAccessToken',
      dir: __dirname,
      file: __filename,
      error:
        error.response && error.response.data ? error.response.data : error,
    });
    return null;
  }
};
```

2. the API route for ms teams authentication that is calling the utility function with the `sso-token` sent from front-end.

```js
router.get('/auth', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      ssoToken,
      teamId,
      teamName = '',
      channelId,
      channelName = '',
    } = req.query;

    const { tid } = jwt_decode(ssoToken);
    if (!tid || !teamId)
      return res
        .status(500)
        .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Could not exchange access token' }] });

    // CALLING THE UTILITY FUNCSTION WITH SSO TOKEN
    const data = await getAccessToken(ssoToken);
    if (!data || !data.access_token)
      res
        .status(403)
        .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'User must consent or perform MFA' }] });

    const { access_token: accessToken, refresh_token: refreshToken } = data;
    console.log({ accessToken, refreshToken });
    if (!accessToken)
      return res
        .status(500)
        .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Could not exchange access token' }] });

    // SUCCESS
    // return 200 status
    //...
  } catch (error) {
    console.error({
      error:
        error.response && error.response.data ? error.response.data : error,
      person: req.person,
      company: req.company,
      headers: req.headers,
      params: req.params,
      url: req.originalUrl,
    });

    // this error should trigger the consent flow in the client.
    res
      .status(403)
      .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'User must consent or perform MFA' }] });
  }
});
```

## Front-end code for step 4 i.e. when consent is required

1. `ConsentPopup.js` (Component responsible for starting the user consentt flow)

```js
class ConsentPopup extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("consentPopUp initialized");

    microsoftTeams.initialize();

    // Get the user context in order to extract the tenant ID
    microsoftTeams.getContext((context, error) => {
      let tenant = context["tid"]; //Tenant ID of the logged in user
      let client_id = env.REACT_APP_AZURE_APP_REGISTRATION_ID;

      let queryParams = {
        tenant: `${tenant}`,
        client_id: `${client_id}`,
        response_type: "token", //token_id in other samples is only needed if using open ID
        // offline_access is Added for RefreshToken
        scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/TeamsActivity.Send offline_access",
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin + "/auth-end",
        nonce: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("base64"),
      };

      let url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?`;
      queryParams = new URLSearchParams(queryParams).toString();
      let authorizeEndpoint = url + queryParams;

      //Redirect to the Azure authorization endpoint. When that flow completes, the user will be directed to auth-end
      // GO TO ClosePopup.js
      console.log(authorizeEndpoint);
      window.location.assign(authorizeEndpoint);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Please wait...</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

2. `ClosePopup.js` (Component responsible for completing the user consentt flow)

```js
class ClosePopup extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
      microsoftTeams.initialize();

      //The Azure implicit grant flow injects the result into the window.location.hash object. Parse it to find the results.
      let hashParams = this.getHashParameters();
      console.log({hashParams});
      //If consent has been successfully granted, the Graph ACCESS TOKEN and REFRESH TOKEN should be present as a field in the dictionary.
      if (hashParams["access_token"]){
        //Notifify the showConsentDialogue function in Tab.js that authorization succeeded. The success callback should fire. 
        //SENDING BOTH REFRESH TOKEN AND ACCESS TOKEN
        microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess(hashParams); 
      } else {
        microsoftTeams.authentication.notifyFailure("Consent failed");
      }
    }

    getHashParameters() {
      let hashParams = {};
      console.log({hash: window.location.hash, hashSubStr: window.location.hash.substr(1)});
      window.location.hash.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {
        let [key,value] = item.split('=');
        hashParams[key] = decodeURIComponent(value);
      });
      console.log('Get Hash Params');
      console.log({hashParams});
      return hashParams;
  }    

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Consent flow complete.</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default ClosePopup;
```

Comment: Please have look into this documentation-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/authentication-oauth-get-tokens?view=bingads-13#refresh-accesstoken

Comment: I have checked it and saw that in the documentation the `response_type` is sent as `code` instead of `token`. I will try that tomorrow and get back to you. 

Thanks for your suggestion @Sayali-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grant (consent) may not be immediate. As of my experience, it can be up to a 30 seconds. I.e. the grant call returns, but the backend still does not "work".

You could try to just keep querying until you get the refresh_token in the second case. I.e. just do it multiple times (in the backend). I.e. try exchanging the sso-token more than once. I think in a few seconds, the refresh_token should start coming.

Comment: What you are suggesting applies to the scenario when extra consent is not required from the user. In that case, I am receiving a refresh token. My problem is in the scenario of extra user consent when the access token, as well as refresh token, is fetched by the front-end using the `authorize` API.

Thanks for your help @Nikolay

Comment: I mean, after you got the consent, you can try to exchange the sso-token to access token multiple times. Just retry the exchange a few more times, that is. And the second scenario will work like the first one after a few attempts.